# Problema al actualizar post

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un crud en el cual tengo que actualizar un post en específico.
Cuando ya tengo 2 o más posts dentro de la lista, si elijo editar el 2do post, al apretar actualizar me borra toda la lista y me muestra solo 1 elemento (el actualizado).
Además, si yo toco solo el body del elemento que deseo actualizar y no asi el *title*, cuando actualizo solo aparece el body el que actualicé y no el titulo.
Además de que se borra de nuevo los otros elementos de la lista que están ya publicadas luego de agregar el post.

Enlace a mi git para que lo veáis mejor: https://github.com/ricardosikic/CRUD-App

Adjunto mi código:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    posts: [],
    singlePost: {},
    isOpen: false
 }

 addNewPost = (post) => {
   const newData = post
   this.setState({
     posts: this.state.posts.concat(newData)
   })
 }

 openModal = (post) => {
   this.setState({
     isOpen: true,
     singlePost: post
   })
 }

 closeModal = (e) => {
   setTimeout(() => {
     this.setState({
       isOpen: false
     })
   }, 1000);
 }

 updatePost = (postEdit) => {
   const index = this.state.posts.findIndex(post => post.i === this.state.posts.i)
   console.log(index)
   const post = this.state.posts.slice(0, index)
   const newData = post.concat(postEdit)

   this.setState({
     posts: newData
   })
 }


 render(){
   return(
     <Fragment>

       <div className="container">
         <div className="row">
           <div className="col-sm-6">
             <Form addNew={e => this.addNewPost(e)} />
           </div>
           <div className="col-sm-6">
             <List posts={this.state.posts} openModal={e => 
   this.openModal(e)}/>
             <Edit active={this.state.isOpen} closeModal={e => 
   this.closeModal(e)} update={e => this.updatePost(e)} post= 
  {this.state.singlePost}/>
           </div>

         </div>
       </div>
     </Fragment>
   );

 }
 }

 export default App;
```

Comment: Hay varias cosas que veo raras en tu código. Lo primero es que cuando haces el `findIndex` estás accediendo a una propiedad (`id`) que no existe en tu objeto posts por lo que siempre te va a devolver el índice cero. Además ten en cuenta que el `slice` te devuelve sólo una parte del array. En este caso no te está devolviendo ningún elemento ya que tanto el índice inicial como el final son 0. Luego haces el `concat` del post editado a un array vacío, de ahí que tu lista se actualice con un único valor.

Comment: @Kiko_L borre las lineas de codigo para esa funcion update lo unico que ahora me pesa es que cada vez que quiero editar un post este si lo edito y actualizo, luego busco otro para editar me aparece en el input del editForm el ultimo valor agregado

Comment: Sí, tendrás que tener un estado para el valor de los inputs y actualizarlo a vacío cada vez que le des a actualizar

Comment: gracias @Kiko_L borre gran parte de la app en esa parte para ver que pasaba con esta, y claro aun me persiste el problema ajaj XD